# SQL CPU peaks with SqlDataAdapter.Fill Command

Tags: c#, database, sqldataadapter

I've noticed some peculiar behaviour getting SQL data into a c# application.  I used a dataset xsd but this began to time out.  I then changed my approach as I already had a class which would generate and return a datatable for other operations I tried that.  This too timed out.

I had opened the Activity Monitor in SSMS to get an idea of what was happening in SQL when the code ran and noticed that which ever way I run it the fill command casuses the SQL Sever to peak at 100% CPU and stay there until the command is cancelled.  This is a good server with plenty of oomph 240Ghz processors and 30GB RAM .  The query is not exactly zippy but returns 100k rows in under 3 seconds in SSMS.

Here is my code for the dataset:

```
        public DataTable UKDataRefresh ()
    {
        UKREFRESH.UKNewContactsDataTable dt = 
            new UKREFRESH.UKNewContactsDataTable();
        UKREFRESHTableAdapters.UKNewContactsTableAdapter ta = 
            new UKREFRESHTableAdapters.UKNewContactsTableAdapter();

        ta.Connection.ConnectionString += ";Password = xxxxxx;";

        try
        {
        ta.Fill(dt, global::SilverPopTransfer.Properties.Settings.Default.UKDATELASTACTION);

        }
        catch (SqlException )
        {

            throw;
        }

        return dt;

    }
```

Here is my code for building it on the fly:

```
public DataTableOperations (string strconnection, string strSelect,string tablename)
{
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
        connection = c;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSelect, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //added this to see what would happen.
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        connection.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, tablename);
        connection.Close();
        Datatable = ds.Tables[tablename];
        _disposed = false;
    }
```

Im looking for clues as to what might cause the problem, not a full solution.
Incidentally I ran a similar function in a pre-existing console application before posting and it connected and ran without error:  the query was almost identical.

The sole difference is that for the pre-existing application I use Integrated security but in this case I specify the user and password.  I **have** confirmed the login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Check index and `set nocount on` before execution. SSMS performance is not a good performance indicator. It get only partial data and executes asynchronous. Try calling a small subset of data or running the query without to fill the table. It can be the bottleneck.

If your are running the select with parameters, sql server will execute it using `sp_execute` then server compile it creating CPE peaks.

Comment: Thanks I had a look at the code and attempted what you suggested: `SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(strSelect, connection); CommandBehavior behave = CommandBehavior.Default; connection.Open(); IAsyncResult result = cmnd.BeginExecuteReader(behave); using (SqlDataReader reader = cmnd.EndExecuteReader(result)) { DisplayResults(reader); } ` This has the same result as before. i.e. massive spikes in the CPU and **a lot** of processes triggering.